# How to sort and filter out given data in React?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Given the data below:

1. Group the items by list id
2. Then sort the results first by list id then by name
3. Filter out the name where is blank or null.

```
[
{"listId": 2, "name": ""},
{"listId": 1, "name": "Item 28"},
{"listId": 1, "name": "Item 270"},
{"listId": 3, "name": null},
{"listId": 4, "name": null},
{"listId": 2, "name": "Item 23"},
{"listId": 1, "name": null},
{"listId": 2, "name": null},
{"listId": 1, "name": ""},
{"listId": 3, "name": null},
{"listId": 2, "name": null},
{"listId": 2, "name": null},
{"listId": 3, "name": "Item 68"},
{"listId": 2, "name": null},
{"listId": 4, "name": "Item 53"},
{"listId": 4, "name": ""},
{"listId": 1, "name": null},
{"listId": 2, "name": null},
]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: what does not work? please add your code.

Comment: [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres a solution that might work for you:

```
const data = [
  {"id": 755, "listId": 2, "name": ""},
  {"id": 203, "listId": 2, "name": "Item 456"},
  {"id": 684, "listId": 1, "name": "Item 684"},
  {"id": 276, "listId": 1, "name": "Item 276"},
  {"id": 736, "listId": 3, "name": null},
  {"id": 926, "listId": 4, "name": null},
  {"id": 808, "listId": 4, "name": "Item 808"},
  {"id": 599, "listId": 1, "name": null},
  {"id": 424, "listId": 2, "name": null},
  {"id": 444, "listId": 1, "name": ""},
  {"id": 809, "listId": 3, "name": "Item 789"},
  {"id": 293, "listId": 2, "name": null},
  {"id": 510, "listId": 2, "name": null},
];

function removeNull({ name }) {
  return Boolean(name);
}

function sortByIdThenName(a, b) {
  const n = a.listId - b.listId;
  // sort by listId
  if (n !== 0) {
    return n;
  }
  // if listId is equal then sort by name
  return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
}

const sorted = data.filter(removeNull).sort(sortByIdThenName);

console.log(sorted);
```

**Response to comments below**

Sort by numeric id found in name:

```
function sortByIdThenIdInName(a, b) {
  const n = a.listId - b.listId;
  // sort by listId
  if (n !== 0) {
    return n;
  }
  // if listId is equal then sort by id in name
  const [, numericIdFromNameA] = a.name.split(' ');
  const [, numericIdFromNameB] = b.name.split(' ');
  
  return parseInt(numericIdFromNameA) - parseInt(numericIdFromNameB);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping out, is it possible to sort the name like "Item 28" comes before "Item 270" instead of "Item 270" comes before "Item 28"? If so how would I be able to do it?

Comment: you would need to split off the id number and sort using the numeric value instead, as we're using localeCompare it's sorting by string value 1 10 100 2 20 200

Comment: I've added to my answer 

Answer (score 0):

My try.

```
var data = [
  { "id": 755, "listId": 2, "name": "" },
  { "id": 203, "listId": 2, "name": "" },
  { "id": 684, "listId": 1, "name": "Item 684" },
  { "id": 276, "listId": 1, "name": "Item 276" },
  { "id": 736, "listId": 3, "name": null },
  { "id": 926, "listId": 4, "name": null },
  { "id": 808, "listId": 4, "name": "Item 808" },
  { "id": 599, "listId": 1, "name": null },
  { "id": 424, "listId": 2, "name": null },
  { "id": 444, "listId": 1, "name": "" },
  { "id": 809, "listId": 3, "name": null },
  { "id": 293, "listId": 2, "name": null },
  { "id": 510, "listId": 2, "name": null },
]

var data = data.filter((d) => d.name)//clean before do anything
data.sort((a, b) => (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : ((b.name > a.name) ? -1 : 0));//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value
function groupBy(arr, key) {//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects
  return arr.reduce(function (rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
}
console.log(groupBy(data, "listId"));
```